# java: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type error when reading .pb file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I try to read .pb extension file. 
Specifically, I would like to read [this dataset](http://iesl.cs.umass.edu/riedel/ecml/) (in .tgz).

I write the following code:

```
Path path = Paths.get(filename);
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
Document document = Document.parseFrom(data);
```

But then I received the following error.

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
```

The last line of the code caused this error, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you saying that you're providing the path of the tgz file? If so, you'd need to untar/unzip it first.

Comment: No, I unzipped it already and provided .pb file as a filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your files are actually in "delimited" format: each one contains multiple messages, each with a length prefix.

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filename);
Document document = Document.parseDelimitedFrom(stream);
```

Keep calling `parseDelimitedFrom(stream)` to read more messages until it returns `null` (end of file).

Also note that the file I looked at -- `testNegative.pb` in `heldout_relations.tgz` -- appeared to contain instances of `Relation`, not `Document`. Make sure you are parsing the correct type, because the protobuf implementation can't tell the difference -- you'll get garbage if you parse the wrong type.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is resolved by using `parseDelimitedFrom()` instead of `parseFrom()` and replacing `Relation` with `Document`. How can I check garbage?

Comment: By "get garbage", I mean the data won't look like what you expect. There's no algorithmic way to do this; you'll need to look manually and "see if it looks right".